# In Emberjs, how do you use in the template file, properties defined in the route?

Tags: ember.js

Say i have a route file like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    [...]
    password: "...",
    [...]
});
```

How do i use the password property in a template?
If i use `{{password}}` it does not work, however, if i define a controller with a password property, i can then use `{{password}}` in the template, but given the fact controllers shouldn't be used anymore, what are my options?

I know that i can do something like this in the route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(){
       return {
            password: "...",
       }
    },
});
```

And then access `{{model.password}}` but i don't think this is the way to go here.

Comment: Have you looked at components?

Comment: @VikramNarayan -  no, i have not, i don't see why complicate things with components for such a basic thing, is this the ember way? My thought is that if you can do it from a controller, you should be able to do it from a route too, otherwise it would be just silly to deprecate controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route sets-up controller and its routes responsibility to pass data to controller,

you can either pass data to controller with `model` hook as you showed above or 
with [setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) hook like:

```
setupController(model, controller) {
 this._super(...arguments);
 var pass = this.get('password');
 controller.set('password', pass);
}
```

there are other ways like accessing route from controller but that will be a hack

Comment: Gotcha, then why say the controllers are deprecated and they should not be used anymore ?

Comment: It is not deprecated yet, they are moving to it but still not there yet, so for now you can use controllers, if it was deprecated you would see warnings in console with some suggestions, you can use it as long as you won't start seeing this warnings I guess :)

Comment: By far the best approach, as in the end it's about setting up some additional data for the template to render. And it will naturally embrace routeable components when they come.